# how to redirect all requests from www.domainA.ext/subdir/ to www.domainB.com/ with htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a new domain (domainB.com) to which I wish to redirect all requests from www.domainA.com/subdir/.
I tried whith this line of htaccess code

```
redirect / http://www.domainB.com/
```

but it doesn't works because htaccess redirects all domainA.com/subdir/ to domainB.com/**subdir**
How can I remove the "subdir"?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule in **`domainA.com/subdir/.htaccess`**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainB.com/$1 [L,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: I had already tried this solution but it doesn't works because, such as I told in my topic, it redirects all request to new 
domain/**subdir_of_old_site**  
I put  
`RedirectMatch ^/(.*)$ http://www.domainB.com/$1`  

(without "subdir" because I want to remove it!) but it doesn't works

Comment: Check updated and it will ONLY redirect `/subdir/*` if you place it in `/subdir/.htaccess`

Comment: maybe I explained badly my problem: with your solution htacces redirects ALL /subdir/ request to the root of the new domain but without the path.  
eg. request from _www.domainA.com/subdir/other/directories_ redirects to _www.domainB.com/index.php_ losing any other piece of url.  To be more clear, I utilise a framework with url rewriting but I think the problem is the same

Comment: Actually this rule will redirect `www.domainA.com/subdir/other/directories` to `www.domainB.com/other/directories` just text it in a new browser.

Comment: I think is a problem of the framework I use, [Yii](http://yiiframework.com/).  In which I have url rewriting actived

Comment: @anubhava hi..pardon me, could you possibly help me over [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227556/extracting-specific-pattern-from-nmap)? thank you.

Comment: I am on mobile. I will look into your question as soon as I get back to my computer.