# Extracting specific pattern from nmap

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, cut

Imagine I have nmap results like so:

```
# Nmap 6.40 scan initiated Sat Jun 14 10:14:35 2014 as: nmap ...
Nmap scan report for x.x.x.x.
Host is up (0.21s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
23/tcp open  telnet
| telnet-brute: 
|_  No accounts found

Nmap scan report for y.y.y.y
Host is up (0.24s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
23/tcp open  telnet

Nmap scan report for z.z.z.z
Host is up (0.22s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
23/tcp open  telnet
|_telnet-brute: var1 - <blank>

Nmap scan report for w.w.w.w
Host is up (0.36s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
23/tcp open  telnet
|_telnet-brute: var2 - var3

Nmap scan report for h.h.h.h
Host is up (0.22s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
23/tcp open  telnet
| telnet-brute: 
|_  No accounts found

Nmap scan report for f.f.f.f
Host is up (0.22s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
23/tcp open  telnet
|_telnet-brute: var4 - <blank>

Nmap scan report for b.b.b.b
Host is up (0.23s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
23/tcp open  telnet
| telnet-brute: 
|_  No accounts found

   
    .
    .
    .

Nmap scan report for a.a.a.a
Host is up (0.22s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
23/tcp open  telnet

# Nmap done at Sun Jun 15 10:20:45 2014 -- 262144 IP addresses (91295 hosts up) scanned in 86769.85 seconds
```

How can I have the result like:

```
z.z.z.z  var1  
w.w.w.w  var2  var3
f.f.f.f  var4
```

I want if there were  doesn't show it. (Better to use `sed`)

## UPDATE

What I tries is:

```
sed -nr '/^Nmap.* /{s///;h};/|_telnet-brute/{n;H;g;s/\n\|\s*/ /;/:/p}' file
```

Thank you

Comment: nmap supports different [output formats](http://nmap.org/book/output.html). You may find the [grepable output format](http://nmap.org/book/output-formats-grepable-output.html) better suited for your processing.

Comment: Thank you @Gumbo for help... but I want to do that with text editors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the one through `grep` with `Perl-regex` option,

```
$ grep -oP "\w\.\w\.\w\.\w|(?<=brute:).*" file | paste - -
x.x.x.x  var1 - <blank>
y.y.y.y  var2 - var3
z.z.z.z
```

**Update:**

```
$ awk -v RS="" '{print $5,$18,$20}' file | awk '$2~/var/ {print}'
z.z.z.z var1 <blank>
w.w.w.w var2 var3
f.f.f.f var4 <blank>
```

If you again want to remove `<blank>` dtring then run,

```
$ awk -v RS="" '{print $5,$18,$20}' file | awk '$2~/var/ {gsub (/<blank>/,""); print}'
z.z.z.z var1 
w.w.w.w var2 var3
f.f.f.f var4
```

OR

You could do this ina single awk command,

```
$ awk -v RS="" '$18~/var/ {gsub (/<blank>/,""); print $5,$18,$20}' file
z.z.z.z var1 
w.w.w.w var2 var3
f.f.f.f var4
```

Comment: How to deny the lines like `z.z.z.z           `?

Comment: then try this if you don't want the third line `grep -oP "\w\.\w\.\w\.\w|(?<=brute:).*" file | paste - - | awk '$2==""{next;}1'`

Comment: Thank you...but this is not showing me ips... I don't know why

Comment: i posted according to your example. Post the nmap log file contents i will try it for you. On regarding to ip's, your regex should be `[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}`

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not consistent (you have `|_telnet` and `| telnet`), but this may give you some:

```
nmap ..... | awk -v RS="" '{print $5,$18,$20}'
```

But as other say, tweak your output before more processing.

Comment: I am only using `|_telnet` lines

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in Perl:

```
$ perl -lne '/for (.+)/; $i=$1; (@f = /var./g) && print "$i @f"' file 
z.z.z.z var1
w.w.w.w var2 var3
f.f.f.f var4
```

#### Explanation

- `perl -lne` : the `-ne` means "read the input file line by line" (`-n`) "and apply the script given as `-e`". The `-l` adds a newline to each `print` call (and removes trailing newlines).
- `/for (.+)/; $i=$1;` : match the word `for` followed by a space and capture (that's what the parentheses do) everything to the end of the line. The captured pattern (`$1`) is saved as `$i`.
- `@f = /var./g` : save all occurrences of `var` and one more character in the array `@f`. If you can have >1 characters following `var`, change that to `@f = /var\w*/g`.
- `&& print "$i @f"` : if the previous match was successful, print `$i` (the IP) and the contents of `@f`.